# How to distribute point from the winner to the loser?

Tags: php, math

Let's explain my problem!
we are coding a website for player of some games we know that the minimum of player is 2 and don't know the maximum of player.
in these games we have a leaderboard (1st,second,...,Last) and we want to distribute for exemple 50 points in an exponential or other way to make graphs.
so here is my question how to give these 50 points to the players with the rules that the first must have the most of points and the last must not have points.

I'm open for suggestions,
and thank all of you who can help me

Comment: The problem would become a lot easier if you don't set the exact number of points to be distributed in advance. So, if there's no good reason to choose 50 points, I would let that restriction go.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this restriction was for an exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remap a priority.

> You were asking the last not having any points, try to add one additional player and remove after calculation.

Let's say we want to distribute 50 points over 10 players by descending priority.

```
$pointsAvailable = 50;
$playerCount = 10;
```

We set some kind of priority.

```
$players = range(1, $playerCount);
$players = array_map(function($p) use ($playerCount, $pointsAvailable) {
    return ($playerCount / $p);
}, $players);
```

Now we know we divide the sum of the distribution by the number of points to get the scalar factor.

```
$pointScalar = $pointsAvailable / array_sum($players);
$players = array_map(function($p) use ($pointScalar) {
    return ($pointScalar * $p);
}, $players);
```

Here you can see the results.

```
print_r($players);
```

```
Array // The points for the players
(
    [0] => 17.07085760737
    [1] => 8.5354288036851
    [2] => 5.6902858691234
    [3] => 4.2677144018426
    [4] => 3.4141715214741
    [5] => 2.8451429345617
    [6] => 2.43869394391
    [7] => 2.1338572009213
    [8] => 1.8967619563745
    [9] => 1.707085760737
)
```

The sum of all points:

```
print_r(array_sum($players));
```

> 50

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise answer and teaching me your knowledge

Comment: Normally the assumption would be that points are not divisible.